# sql syntax for update using php oci

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Any thoughts on why the query works in SQLDeveloper but in php it doesn't?

```
$update = " update TABLENAME SET LASTMOD=current_timestamp WHERE TABLE_NAME=$table ";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $update);
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
oci_free_statement($stmt);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that your variable `$table` does not include quotes and it must be quoted in the `WHERE` clause:

```
$update = " update TABLENAME SET LASTMOD=current_timestamp WHERE TABLE_NAME='$table'";
```

A call to `oci_error()` would reveal any syntax errors in your query.

Note also, that according to the documentation, if this is PL/SQL the statement must end in a `;` as

```
$update = " update TABLENAME SET LASTMOD=current_timestamp WHERE TABLE_NAME='$table';";
```

The statement would be better done as a proper prepared statement though, with bound parameters:

```
$update = " update TABLENAME SET LASTMOD=current_timestamp WHERE TABLE_NAME=:table;";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $update);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':table', $table);
$result = oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
if (!$result) {
  echo oci_error();   
}
```

Comment: thanks for properly prepared statement, though that didn't fix the problem. the problem was oci_default not committing.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. OCI_DEFAULT doesn't commit so I needed to change it to:

```
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
```